# Ocaml Error Unbound Value when using Recursion

Tags: recursion, ocaml

My code is very basic as I am pretty new to ocaml
I am trying to call a function recursively but I am getting an unbound value error message on the name of the function

```
let count_help x a lst = match lst with 
    [] -> a
    | (s,i)::t -> if s = x then count_help x a+1 t else count_help x a t
;;

let count_assoc lst x =
    count_help x 0 lst
;;
```

The error is Unbound value count_help on the line that calls count_help inside of count_help

This code is simply suppose to count the number times an association appears for the given character x

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to say

```
let rec count_help ...
```

to allow the name `count_help` to be used recursively within its definition.